# Ligar para numero USSD IONIC

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou tentando ligar para um numero *USSD* da minha aplicação *IONIC*, segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="tel:*000#">IOD</ion-item>
```

Porém ele aparece no discador do celular apenas o numero `*000` ignorando o `#`, alguém já passou por isso e sabe como resolver?

Comment: A pergunta é boa, mas seria uma brecha de segurança violenta se fosse permitido USSD neste tipo de link. Provavelmente só conseguiria usando alguma função nativa, e ainda é capaz de precisar de permissão do OS. Por USSD um link malicioso conseguiria ativar e desativar serviços, redirecionar chamadas, interceptando ligações do usuário, entre várias outras coisas indesejáveis.

Comment: Uai, mas sera que somente com app nativo teria como fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Para torná-lo funcional que você precisa para fornecer acesso em `config.xml`, adicione:

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

<sup>Fonte: [it1me.com](http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=35196136&ttl=How+to+send+and+receive+USSD+codes+with+ionic+platform%3F)</sup>

Comment: Cara ate coloquei isso, mas continua dando o mesmo erro...aparentemente não e isso.
Brigadão